# Is it possible to deploy CRM 2011 on premise without Domain Administrator rights?

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics-crm

We are installing an **on-premise** CRM 2011. We are using an OU in the corp AD domain but we **don't have Domain Admin rights**. Is it possible to have a successful deployment? I heard that it is important to have domain admin rights.

Answer (score 3):

This is not needed, but it sure does make the installation much easier.

The Admin rights are required because CRM will create some groups and accounts in AD during the installation.

To install CRM 2011 witout using the administrator account, you will need to create a domain account and give it some permissions on the CRM, SQL and AD, this link from Microsoft will show you all the setup you need in terms of permissions.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699825.aspx

Thanks,